# Comparing something something to a data type (like char, string, etc.)

Tags: java

I started programming Java 3 Weeks ago, because we started it in School.
Now I got a Question, I hope, you can help me!

I want to compare a Variable (in my Case a Integer) to a Data Type:

```
int a;
(...)
if (a != int) {
System.out.println ("I can only work with Integers")
}
else { }
```

So everytime, if I type into the Scanner a Char or Double or something different than an Integer, the Program will give a different Output or an Error.

Can you help me, how to compare the Both Types?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Look at the Scanner API. Specifically the  “hasNextInt “ method.

Comment: Look at the `instanceof` operator: i.e. `if ( a instanceof Integer )`

Comment: How about using your Exception class?

Answer (score 1):

To check a type of variable in Java you can use the *instanceof* operator.

Example :

```
if(a instanceof String) {
System.out.println("This is a String!");
}
```